# the path of the report does not change after changing the name of the folder in jasperServer

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I have a folder `(cat1)` in jasperServer  which contains some reports. After changing the name of the folder using the web interface to `category1`, the paths of reports which are inside this folder does not change. For example, report1 still has the path `/reports/cat1/report1` and not `/reports/category1/report1`

How to solve this issue ?

Comment: I think the report itself has a reference in which path it resides. So this reference must also be altered.

Comment: thanks @tobi6, but how could we find where to modify this reference?

Comment: [JasperReports REST API v2 - Moving Resources](http://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/jasperreports-server-web-services-guide/v56/moving-resource)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by moving the resource as proposed in [jasperServer rest client API](https://github.com/Jaspersoft/jrs-rest-java-client#moving-a-resource).

```
OperationResult<ClientResource> result = client
        .authenticate("jasperadmin", "jasperadmin")
        .resourcesService()
        .resource("/reports/category1/report1")
        .moveFrom("/reports/cat1/report1");
```